# How to Convert a valid JSObject STRING to a JSON STRING without using eval

Tags: javascript, json

I want to allow a user to input custom objects into a text area.
If I require them to write proper json it would look like this

```js
{ "field1": 10, "field2": "string" }
```

then I can simply grab the input field and do

```js
let obj = JSON.parse('{ "field1": 10, "field2": "string" }')
```

To make their life easier I can also allow strings of Javascript objects..

```js
{ field1: 10, field2: "string", }
```

then I can use eval

```js
let obj
eval('obj = ' + '{ field1: 10, field2: "string"}')
```

HOWEVER eval is unsafe, a user can type something like `10; alert('hi')`;

So My questions:
Is there a way of converting a valid Javascript Object String into a valid JSON String without using `eval`?

I was thinking it might be possible with one or more regex/replace operations.
ie

```js
let jsObjString =  '{ field1: 10, field2: "string", }'
jsObjString = addQuotesToKeysIfMissing(jsObjString );
jsObjString  = removeTrailingCommas(jsObjString );
console.log(jsObjString )
// { "field1": 10, "field2": "string" }
let obj = JSON.parse(jsobjString)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what is the problem using `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @NinaScholz because it ain't JSON....

Comment: Is it possible? yes, but it is a bit complicated. It is not a simple reg exp when you throw in edge cases on what can be entered.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not put the user input into JSON? Not sure how you are requesting the data, but there are certainly ways to build JSON from their input (e.g. do not make them write strings...)

Comment: https://ryanmarcus.github.io/dirty-json/

Comment: I'm ok with a partial solution, Keys have quotes and no trailing commas. If the parse works I'll parse, if not, at worse the user would need to input real json.